# Unhandled exception type IOException in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse to write the code and I get a red underline at `customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();` and it says

> Unhandled exeption type IOException.

Why does this happen and how could I solve it?

```
// Call method in customHandler class to write to file when button is pressed
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    // Save transactions to file
    if(event.getSource()== buttonSaveTransaction)
    {
         customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();
    }
}

// Method in class customHandler that writes to file
public void saveTransactionToFile() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Skriver till fil");
    File outFile = new File("C:/JavaBank/" + selectedCustomerAccountNumber + ".data");
    FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
    outStream.println("test");
    outStream.close();  
}
```

Comment: Click the red bullet which Eclipse shows left from the line and try one of the suggestions to auto-fix it. In the meanwhile, learn how to deal with exceptions in Java by reading the vendor's tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: probably did not include a library file - try import java.io - you figure out which specific io library you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your actionPerformed() method ,, write

```
customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();
```

write this like

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    // Save transactions to file
    if(event.getSource()== buttonSaveTransaction)
    {
        try
        {
            customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

To answer as to why you have to do this **"It's because the method being called for i.e.                `customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();`, is known to throw IOException as mentioned by you in the definition."**

Hope that will help

Regards

Comment: Thanks! But what is it the code is doing and why is this necessary? Is just because it's an actionlistener or is it necessary for all method calling other methods with save to file things?

Comment: @3D-kreativ : No its not because its an actionListener, since you are calling a method that might can throw IOException, that is why it has to be inside the try catch block. IOException (Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations). Hope this might help . Regards

Comment: Thanks, a little bit hard to understand how it works, but is working!

Comment: @3D-kreativ : Your Welcome, hope this link will further help you understand as to why it happened. [Exception Handling TUTORIALS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)  BEST OF LUCK and Regards :-)

Answer (score 3):

since `saveTransactionToFile` throws an exception, `actionPerformed`, which calls that method, need to catch and handle it.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    // Save transactions to file
    if(event.getSource()== buttonSaveTransaction)
    {
         try {
             customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();
         } catch(IOException e) { 
             // I broke, make sure you do something here, so the user
             // knows there was an error
         }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to handle the exception here (or in `saveTransactionToFile`).  `actionPerformed` cannot throw checked exceptions....

Comment: or to delegate it to the caller by `throws` if the method can by itself not handle it in any sensible way.

Comment: @3D: Just the same as you already did on `saveTransactionToFile()` method. But in this particular case, I'd just catch it and show some message dialog informing the enduser that saving has failed. *That* is a sensible way of dealing with the exception. Just printing the stacktrace and ignoring it further as some answers suggest is *not* sensible and leaves the enduser with an open question where the heck the saved file is.

Comment: @balsusC what do you mean `by throws`?  He can't throw it (I guess he could throw a RuntimeException). You mean put the caller in the actionPerformed scope?

Comment: Thanks, a little bit hard to understand how it works, but is working!

Answer (score 1):

Surround it in a try catch

```
try
{
    if(event.getSource()== buttonSaveTransaction)
    {
         customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
 //manage exception 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, and also see the answer by hvgotcodes.

```
try {
    customHandler.saveTransactionToFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```